# Is it possible to convert neural imaging informatics (.nii) file to a jpeg using php?

Tags: php, file, type-conversion, medical

I have been converting .nii files to jpeg images using [this tool](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8797-tools-for-nifti-and-analyze-image) manually. Currently, i would like to let the system do this for me using php.

i have excellent knowledge in php but i have not tried converting .nii files to jpeg using php because i dont understand .nii files very well.

```
   a=load_nii('file.nii')
   a_images=a.img
   imtool(a_images(:,:,image_number),[])
```

i just want a php syntax to convert .nii file to a jpeg image